# Strange behavior of logRotate?

Tags: logrotate

I have the following configuration of logrotate:

```
/var/log/test/app.log {
        missingok
        notifempty
        compress
        copytruncate
        daily
        rotate 4
}
```

The application generating the log is a Java application.
2
I set up this configuration yesterday before midnight.
Today in the morning I noticed that logRotate made a file called "app.log.1", which only had log entries between 8:21 AM and 10:05 AM. app.log was logging since 10:05 AM.
All the logs before 8:21 AM were missing! Furthermore, "app.log.1" wasn't even compressed.

Do you know what could've caused this?

Comment: Please edit your question to add contents of the file /etc/logrotate.conf

Answer (score 1, accepted):

is your java application using log4j?
perhaps the app has a rollingfileappender configured, so the logrotation came from the app itself not from your logrotate configuration.